# How important it is to support Dark mode for iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-darkmode

We have built an app which will be available in AppStore in couple of months. This app has almost 40 screens. Right now there is no support for iOS 13's Dark mode feature. Is it worth to do that? Applications which are huge and already live, how are they planning to make this change?

Comment: Dark mode is a must for any app. Well if your app already has large number of active users, it is important to have dark mode. If your app has lots of competition then users might switch in favor of other app with proper dark mode support. There are many user that use automatic or dark theme for iOS - switching to your app from system or dark mode supported app will have very bad user experience. If you use swiftUI then maybe wait for a month as xcode 12 has quick dark mode preview by default making dev faster

Comment: The sooner you adopt it the better. You just need to take advantage of the dynamic colors. This way the app would respond automatically to the UI changes

Answer (score 1):

I saw a writing before that says Apple will make developers compulsory to develop apps with dark theme. For now, I think that's not so important to have dark mode for an app. But in the future, it may be a standard.

Comment: Can you share the reference for the line where it says "Apple will make developers compulsory to develop apps with dark theme"

Answer (score 1):

If you care of your users, it is very important to support dark mode. It is a very bad user experience to be in Dark mode and then switch to an app that will be full bright. Very unpleasant user experience.
Yes, it requires some work, but, IMHO, you should support dark mode ASAP. That may also be an opportunity to improve some views design.